# Spring 4 Attribute 'items' must be an array, a Collection or a Map

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i have this error when create a Combobox item in Spring 4.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'items' must be an array, a Collection or a Map
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractMultiCheckedElementTag.writeTagContent(AbstractMultiCheckedElementTag.java:234)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
```

...

I have POJO Class `Student` :

```
    public class Student {
        @Size(min=3, max=30)
        private String firstName;

        @Size(min=3, max=30)
        private String lastName;

        @NotEmpty
        private String sex;

        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
        @Past @NotNull
        private Date dob;

        @Email @NotEmpty
        private String email;

        @NotEmpty
        private String section;

        @NotEmpty
        private String country;

        private boolean firstAttempt;

        @NotEmpty
        private List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();
...
```

I create method in my Controller and Annotate it with `@ModelAttribute`

```
@ModelAttribute("sections")
    public List<String> initializeSections() {
        List<String> sections = new ArrayList<String>();
        sections.add("Graduate");
        sections.add("Post Graduate");
        sections.add("Research");

        return sections;
    }
```

Here is my JSP :

```
...
<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label class="col-xs-3" for="section">Section</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                        <form:radiobuttons path="section" items="${sections}"/>
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="section" class="help-inline" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
...
```

When i run, i get above Error message.
How to fix that? What is missing?

Comment: What happens when you just print `${sections}` from your JSP?

Answer (score 2):

> **Answer ✓**
>
> I missing one thing, i have to add this `isELIgnored="false"`, i found
>   this according instruction from **@JB Nizet** to print out my `EL`. If you
>   create webapp project from Maven, you must declare `isELIgnored="false"` manually.
>
> Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to generate multiple radio buttons, and the values at runtime.
Modify controller code as follows and try.

```
@ModelAttribute("sections")
public Map<String, List<String>> initializeSections() {
    List<String> sections = new ArrayList<String>();
    sections.add("Graduate");
    sections.add("Post Graduate");
    sections.add("Research");

    Map<String, List<String>> sectionData = new HashMap<>();
    sectionData.put("sections", sections);

    return sectionData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Include the above statement at the top of your jsp file